# How to deal with interface errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gtk

Ive just installed a fresh new Eclipse "Neon". I've mentioned that some elements of the UI are looking strange like the main-menu or some widgets like the dropdown-menues within the config-menues (see screenshots).

How can I deal with it so that eclipse stops looking like its broken?

My Java-Version is

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web for a solution I found that the error must based on a problem with GTK-3.0 in eclipse.

When launching eclipse like this `export SWT_GTK3=0; ./eclipse` It will work perfectly. Just if anybody has similar issues.